# Can't set both ContentTemplateSelector and Template properties on a DataGridColumnHeader

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, controltemplate, datagridcolumnheader, contenttemplateselector

In short, the question title says it all. For those that want more detail, here is the crux of my problem: I need to apply a custom `ControlTemplate` to the `DataGridColumnHeader` elements in my `DataGrid` control, but I also need to style them differently, depending on the cell data nearest the header. However, when I set both the `ContentTemplateSelector` *and* `Template` properties on a `DataGridColumnHeader` element, the `DataTemplateSelector` that is set as the value of the `ContentTemplateSelector` property is not called. Commenting out the `Template` property setting confirms this to be the case, as the `DataTemplateSelector` element will now be called.

Yes, I know that you guys love to see some code, but I have completely templated the whole `DataGrid` control to look like Excel, so as you can imagine, I have far too much code to display here. But just to please you code hungry devs, I've recreated my problem in a much simpler example... let's first see the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.Items>
                <System:String>One</System:String>
                <System:String>Two</System:String>
                <System:String>Three</System:String>
            </DataGrid.Items>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Local:StringDataTemplateSelector x:Key="StringDataTemplateSelector" />
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource StringDataTemplateSelector}" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now the most simple `DataTemplateSelector` class:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class StringDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the XAML, we see a `DataGrid`, with just one `DataGridTemplateColumn` and three string values, one on each row, and some resources. There is a `Style` for the `DataGridColumnHeader` element in the `Resource` section, with the most simple `ControlTemplate` set up for it, that only includes the required named parts from the default `ControlTemplate`.

If you run the application as it is, then it will NOT currently break at the `Debugger.Break()` method in the `StringDataTemplateSelector` class. This is unexpected. If you now comment out the setting of the `Template` property in the `Style` and run the application again, then you will now see that program execution will now break at the `Debugger.Break()` method, as expected.

**Further information**:

In the Remarks section of the [`ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) page of MSDN, it states that

> If both the `ContentTemplateSelector` and the `ContentTemplate` properties are set, then this property is ignored.

However, it does *not* mention the `Template` property and there is also no mention of this on the [`Control.Template` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Furthermore, I tried this same setup using a simple `Button` control and can confirm that setting both the `ContentTemplateSelector` and the `ContentTemplate` properties on that does NOT stop the `StringDataTemplateSelector` class from being called:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Local:StringDataTemplateSelector x:Key="StringDataTemplateSelector" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource StringDataTemplateSelector}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <Button Content="One" />
    <Button Content="Two" />
    <Button Content="Three" />
</ItemsControl>
```

So, what I'm after is a way to apply a custom `ControlTemplate` element to the `DataGridColumnHeader` objects, yet still be able to have the `DataTemplateSelector` class called during the rendering process.

Answer (score 1):

add a content presenter in your controltemplate?

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Grid>
           <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
           <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
           <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I have minimised my code to display here. I have no problem displaying the data. My problem is that the `DataTemplateSelector` will not run when the `Template` property is also set.

Comment: i get inside DataTemplateSelector once i add the content presenter in your Template, you do not?

Comment: Hmmm... that's interesting. But in my actual `ControlTemplate`, I *do* have a `ContentPresenter`, and that does not make the `DataTemplateSelector` run.

Comment: apparently, the default controltemplate for datagridcolumnheader is exactly what i posted above, just that ContentPresenter is inside a DataGridHeaderBorder, the thing with that hardcoded sorting behavior. it makes no sense to me that the default template works fine, but using a pretty much same template doesnt

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make much sense to me either. I also have the `DataGridHeaderBorder` element from the default `ControlTemplate` in my template... in fact, it *is* the default `ControlTemplate`, but just with an extra element. I'll see if I can work out a better example.

Comment: did you perhaps also edit the DataGrid.Template and remove the DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter in some situations? or made it invisible depending on something?

Comment: No, every part of the original `ControlTemplate` is definitely still there. All I did was add additional elements here and there.

Comment: did you find a solution mayhaps? or a way to reproduce it in a new example?

Comment: No sorry, I couldn't reproduce the problem any better, as I've had to work on other projects. It's still a problem and I'll try to get back to this when I can. +1 for your help so far though. ;)